# How do I parse a number more than '9' in c #?

Tags: c#

Eg.      if (RoomNumber = int.Parse(roomnotextBox.Text) == '11')

I tried to use this statement in c# but it shows that I have an error as it has too many characters. May I know how am I able to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using a string to compare an integer here?

Single Characters are single quotes 'c' and a string literal is contained within double quotes "my string".

```
var myInteger = int.Parse("11");
if (myInteger == 11) 
{
   // True...
}
```

If you are comparing strings:

```
var myString = "11";
if (myString == "11") 
{ 
   // True ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

String literals are encapsulated in quotes, not apostrophes, hence the error message about too many characters. However, you're comparing an int to a string and also assigning a boolean to a variable named 'RoomNumber'...

`if (int.Parse(roomnotetextBox.Text) == 11)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to protect you code against user input you could try something like

```
int number;
if (int.TryParse(roomnotextBox.Text, out number) && number == 11)
{
   // your code here
}
```

If you use `int.Parse` and the user enter a none numeric character it will throw a `FormatException`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (RoomNumber = int.Parse(roomnotextBox.Text) == 11) { ... }
```

You would be comparing int to 11.